# Tensorflow data validation for tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-data-validation

Is there any version of Tensorflow data validation (tfdv) that can work with tensorflow 2.0 alpha ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct correlation between TFX (includes tfdv) and the deep learning framework of tensorflow.

Comment: Thank you. I have installed tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0 and tensorflow-model-analysis==0.13.2  apache-beam[gcp]==2.11.0 . when calling import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma the following error is being fired:      16 
     17 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 18 from tensorflow_transform import coders

ImportError: cannot import name coders . Any advise what might it be? if needed, I will call TFMA from another notebook. Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to check github of model analysis : https://github.com/tensorflow/model-analysis#compatible-versions

Comment: thank you for your response. the formal answer is no. Since everything is new, there might be a way to make it work. anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supporting TF 2.0 end-to-end in TFX (Transform, TF Data Validation, Model Analysis) is currently a work in progress.

Please refer this Github Issue for more info,
https://github.com/tensorflow/model-analysis/issues/45